# I came across this sign in PHP " ? 0 : ".What does it mean?

Tags: php

This condition was found in this function:

```
$kValues = getValueCluster($clusters, $data);
        foreach($cPos as $k => $position)
        {
                $cPos[$k] = empty($kValues[$k]) ? 0 : avg($kValues[$k]);
        }
        return $cPos
```

I have been trying to find out what this is. I've searched it in google and it has nothing on it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Please don't ask so fast a question! Just put 5min of effort in it!

Comment: I've been searching in google and I could not find any information on it. Up until this question I found out it was an ternary operator.

Comment: I still don't understand when to use it and how to use it.

Comment: It can be used to do an `if-then-else` within an expression. **Why should I use it?** Because it is an expression. `if-then-else` is a control structure. This can be very useful when calling methods. With `if-then-else` you need to ensure, that `setSomeState()` is called in either block.

Comment: *"I still don't understand when to use it and how to use it."* - have you bothered to read the PHP docs?  It's all there buddy.

Comment: I'm a slow learner but i got it down now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`... ? ... : ...` is a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It exists in a [lot of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's used like that:

```
variable = test ? assignIfTrue : assignIfFalse;
```

In your case, `$cPos[$k]` will be assigned to `0` if `$kValues[$k]` is empty and to `avg($kValues[$k])` if not.

Comment: You should - for the clarity's sake - don't call it **the** ternary operator. Beginners could easily missunderstand that and start to believe, that there is only just one ternary operator in the world ;-) Better say: it *is a* ternary operator, that evaluates to the second operand, iff the first evaluates to true and to the third, otherwise.

Comment: You're right, even if no other one comes to my mind right now. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That's PHP's [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Basic example:

```
$x = true;
$y = $x ? 'true!' : 'false';
```

Comment: what does it mean?
what is it doing in this foreach?

Comment: @student If there are values, it's calculating the average. If there are no values, it's setting the average to zero.